# EF 6.1 Conditional Mapping With Boolean?

Tags: entity-framework

Trying to filter objects where the soft delete column isDeleted = false. isDeleted is a property of the object, so it throws exception:

Conditional member isDeleted with a condition other than isNull=False is mapped. Either remove the condition or remove it from the mapping.

I understand this exception is thrown because EF will only allow a property to be mapped once. And with the condition i am attempting to map it twice, however i need the isDeleted property for the soft deletes.

My questions: Is it possible with model-first to have EF handle the soft deletes such that i no longer need the property and may use it as a conditional mapping?

Is there a different way to have EF not display soft deleted objects?

Comment: Find some inspiration [here](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html).

Comment: I did review that prior to posting. That approach is for code-first. Im wondering if it is possible with model-first